# Upsert functionality in azure cosmosdb

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-cosmosdb

Can somebody explain to me what is the logic behind upsert method since coming from an SQL world I don't quite get it why it is not working as intended.

Say I have a container called "products". I set the partition key to "category_id". I also set unique key to "sku".

Then I have this object I want to store with container.items.upsert() method:

```
const product= { sku: 1, name: "MyAwesomeProduct", category_id: 100 }
```

First iteration with upsert works just fine. Now if I want to "insert or update" product(s) and say I just add this one again but change the value of "name" to "UpdatedAwesomeProduct" and try to upsert it, Azure returns an error that an item with the same key already exists. I just wanted to update its name.   Do I need to query the item with sku first and determine whether to create or update it separately after?

Comment: Hard to tell what the issue is without any code. Please edit your question to show your upsert code.

Comment: Also please clarify the API you're using (I can guess SQL API but you didn't tag it as such)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is first understanding what is the **item identity**.

In Cosmos DB, an item identity is the `id` and Partition Key.

If I Upsert an item with `id` A and Partition Key `X` and there is no other item that exists previously with this `id` and Partition Key, then it will get created.

If I call Upsert again with the same `id` and Partition Key with some other property change, then the item will get updated/replaced.

In your example, your `product` does not have `id` so what will probably happen is that the `id` is auto-generated as a `Guid`.
So calling twice, will generate 2 **different items**.

The reason your second Upsert fails however is because of your Unique Key. Unique Key constraints mean that **within a Partition Key** no 2 items can have the same Unique Key value, so within the `category_id` `100` there cannot be 2 items with `sku` `1`. Because your Upsert is not specifying `id` and letting it auto-generate, then it is trying to create a second document and that fails the Unique Key violation.

Comment: FYI OP still hasn't shown any details of what they're doing - no code or anything (hence my comments under the question).

Comment: I got it working. The problem was that I did not provide an id myself and tried to upsert with the same sku that was set as a unique field. So I had to change the "sku" to "id" and re-create the container without setting a unique key identifier. Also the "id" of the product (record) had to be a STRING value.